# Sizeable screenshot UI code

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, user-interface, screenshot

I am in need of someway to access the UI for the screenshot command in OSX (Cmd+Shft+4) and I would like to be able to activate the UI with a UI button that will screenshot the region selected and save it to a temp location. 
Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 1):

If there's a direct way to do this from Cocoa, maybe someone will chime in... but I doubt it exists.  You can, however, get any behavior you want from the "screencapture" command line utility; it does exactly the same as Cmd-Shift-3 or 4 with a gazillion options.  Just type "man screencapture" in Terminal to see all the flags.

But this would require you to run a bash script from your app.  If you haven't done that before, well, google it, or check out the many threads here on SO... Opinions vary on how complicated it should be, from a one-liner call to system() to fully thread-safe error reporting NSTask and all kinds of answers in between.

I'd recommend using one of the NSTask answers which keep themselves to half a dozen lines, but YMMV.